# Usar '?' dentro de un endpoint con Express

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

mi consulta viene porque debo hacer una API REST con node.js + express en la cual me llega por ejemplo un request de este estilo:

> GET /movies?name=nombre

Haciendo pruebas, con un codigo como el siguiente:

```
app.get(`/api/movies?name=:name`, (req, res) => {
res.send(`Movie name: ${req.params.name}`)});
```

La pagina me devuelve

> Cannot GET /api/movies

Al ingresar con la ruta:

> http://localhost:3000/api/movies?name=example

Buscando en la documentacion de express vi que el '?' lo usan como una especie de operador:

> Estos son algunos ejemplos de vías de acceso de ruta basadas en
> patrones de serie.
>
> Esta vía de acceso de ruta coincidirá con acd y abcd.
>
> `app.get('/ab?cd', function(req, res) {   res.send('ab?cd'); });`

¿Hay alguna forma de configurar express para que responda al endpoint que me estan pidiendo?

Codigo:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();

app.set("port",3000||process.env.PORT);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.get('/api/movies?name=:name', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`Movie name: ${req.params.name}`)
  })

app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${app.get("port")}`)

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El operador `?` se utiliza en la URL para determinar el fin del recurso y el inicio de los queryParams. En express.js tiene una connotación de parámetro opcional

Normalizaría ese recurso y tenemos dos vías

**Por params**

```
app.get('/api/movies/:movie', (req, res) => {
  const movie = req.params.movie;
  res.send(`Movie name: ${movie}`);
});
// localhost:3000/api/movies/troya -> Movie name: troya
```

Si intentas acceder al recurso sin troya, te lanzará un error, por que la `movie` es requerida

```
// localhost:3000/api/movies/ -> Cannot GET /api/movies
```

Puedes dejarla opcional agregando el `?` a la ruta

```
app.get('/api/movies/:movie?', (req, res) => {
  const movie = req.params.movie;
  res.send(`Movie name: ${movie}`);
});
// localhost:3000/api/movies/ -> Movie name:
```

**Por queryParams**

No hay mapa exacto de los parámetros que van a llegar, pueden venir 5, pero si solo estás mapeando 2, los demás serán ignorados, lo ejemplifico

```
app.get('/api/movies', (req, res) => {
  const name = req.query.name;
  res.send(`Movie name: ${movie}`);
});
// localhost:3000/api/movies?name=troya -> Movie name troya
```

Ahora, pueden mandarte cualquier parámetro, sin importar si lo tomas o no
Imagina esta ruta:

```
// localhost:3000/api/movies?name=troya&actor=BradPitt&book=Iliada&bookAuthor=Homero

app.get('/api/movies', (req, res) => {
  console.log( req.query );
  /* {
   name: 'Troya',
   actor: 'BradPitt',
   book: 'Iliada',
   bookAuthor: 'Homero'
  } */
});
```

Puedes o no puedes tomar, quizá solo te sirva el bookAuthor, y los demás parámetros sean irrelevantes para este recurso.
Sin embargo, express.js está diseñado para construir REST API, es mucho más eficiente y limpio hacerlo. Te dejo documentación de [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/mx-es/cloud/learn/rest-apis), aunque hay mucho más en el mercado